# Select all columns of combobox

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a combobox on a userform. This combobox exists out of four columns. This is an example of the data in the userform:

```
Week 1: | 01-01-2015 | - | 07-01-2015
Week 2: | 08-01-2015 | - | 14-01-2015
Week 3: | 15-01-2015 | - | 21-01-2015
```

Now, when I select one of the options, for example week 2, my selection of the combobox will change to `Week 2:`, while I want it to change to     `Week 2: | 08-01-2015 | - | 14-01-2015`

I know I actually should use listboxes for these kind of things, but I don't like the looks of a listbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. However, be aware that after you change the text to the "mixed string", you will no longer be able to retrieve the selected `ListIndex`

```
Private Sub ComboBox5_Change()
    Dim i As Integer
    With ComboBox5
        i = .ListIndex: If i < 0 Then Exit Sub
        .Text = .List(i, 0) & " | " & .List(i, 1) & " | " & .List(i, 2) & " | " & .List(i, 3)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Excuse me for the late reaction. I'm getting an error `Runtime error 380. Can't set Text property. Invalid property value`. The values inside the .Lists are in the correct format

Comment: I figured the problem is that my Style perperty is set as a DropDownList style. I guess I'll change this back and check the input before passing it through to the sub